# Executing C++ in VS code is not Clean

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, vscode-debugger

[VS code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIsgR.png)

Hii, Im trying to execute C++ program in VS code in ubuntu 16.04 but the output i get is mixed with other things like I've shown in screenshot the same if i execute in terminal I get the clean output of my program without getting mixed with other things like these :-

```
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-qdt8mbun.gul" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-z70qnvlb.zrn
```

how shall I get rid of it in VS code.

Comment: because you use a debugger when you run inside VSC

Answer (score 1):

In vscode, using `ctrl+f5` will generally cann't take input in the programme. For this you have to manually set task.json file.

Here i have configured my vs code for that.By pressing `ctrl+shtf+b` it will take input and show output.You can check it out.

[VS Code Setting (Live input output) to make competitive programming easy and program analysis](https://github.com/jspw/VS-Code-Config).

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYO3aCP1Gmk&t=21s)

Comment: what is the added value of the image